# Excel create list of names, excluding name selected from drop down list

Tags: excel

I am new to more advanced excel formulas. I have an issue with what I think should be pretty basic functionality, however I have not found an applicable answer.

Worksheet2 has a list of 10 distinct names. Worksheet1 (B2) has data validation drop-down list populated with the names in Worsheet2.  I want to copy the list of names from Worksheet2 (starting in cell B4), excluding name selected from drop-down list.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried? Post your code, if you dont have any than I suggest you give it a try and post back with code where you are stuck.

Comment: I am an excel novice, so I am not knowledgeable about code.  Does this type of functionality require coding?  Up to this point I have tried various VLOOKUP and MATCH formulas that have not worked.